# How to edit this file?

Tags: python, xml

I've got a datafile which is a .MET file, it a file from a GPSmeasuring tool. It can be opened in notepad etc. and it looks like this.

```
<VERSIE>1.0</VERSIE>
<REEKS>NAME</REEKS>
<PROFILE>profilename, profilename,date,#,NAP,ABS,#,XY,x,y
<MEASUREMENT>#,#,x,y,z,z</MEASUREMENT>
<MEASUREMENT>#,#,x,y,z,z</MEASUREMENT>
<MEASUREMENT>#,#,x,y,z,z</MEASUREMENT>
...
<MEASUREMENT>#,#,x,y,z,z</MEASUREMENT>
</PROFILE>
<PROFILE>
...
</PROFILE>
```

I need to calculate something with the all the x's and y's in the measurement of the entire profile.
However, I don't know how to access the file in python.
A friend of mine suggested converting it to XML.
And when I tried to access them through `xm.etree.Elementree`

```
tree = ET.parse('Data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for PROFIEL in root:
    print(MEASUREMENT.tag, MEASUREMENT.attrib)
```

I could convert them to a .csv/excel file in excel, but I rather skip that part, because I'd like to do the entire process in python. And make sure I can do it for several different files.
Anyone got a suggestion on how to access/edit these files?

Comment: It is not clear why your friends suggestion for how to read that file using Python doesn't work for you.

Comment: It gives the following error:
ParseError: junk after document element: line 2, column 0
when i delete that line it gives it at line 14, which is a regular measurement line

Comment: Have you tried the file in an XML checker online?

Comment: I guess something went wrong with converting.
It says: Only one top lever element is allowed in an xml document.
Any tips on converting from .txt to XML?(Notepad++ XML plug-in)

Comment: XML is just text. Perhaps try putting a single XML element around all the others to make the XML legal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As *ostergaard* suggested, you need to put a single element around everything else to make the XML legal.

The simplest way to do it is probably using `ET.XML()` which takes a `str`. Though you could use a `io.StringIO` as a *file-like object* if you really wanted to use `ET.parse()`.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

filename = r"C:\Users\PFeatherbottom\Desktop\measurements.xml" # raw strings are nice
with open(filename) as file:
    root = ET.XML(f"<root>{file.read()}</root>") # and so are f-strings

for profile in root.findall("PROFILE"):
    print("Profile text:", profile.text.strip())
    for measurement in profile.findall("MEASUREMENT"):
        print("Measurement text:", measurement.text)
```

Output:

```
Profile text: profilename, profilename,date,#,NAP,ABS,#,XY,x,y
Measurement text: #,#,x,y,z,z
Measurement text: #,#,x,y,z,z
Measurement text: #,#,x,y,z,z
Measurement text: #,#,x,y,z,z
Profile text:
```

This was my `measurements.xml` input file, btw:

```
<VERSIE>1.0</VERSIE>
<REEKS>NAME</REEKS>
<PROFILE>profilename, profilename,date,#,NAP,ABS,#,XY,x,y
<MEASUREMENT>#,#,x,y,z,z</MEASUREMENT>
<MEASUREMENT>#,#,x,y,z,z</MEASUREMENT>
<MEASUREMENT>#,#,x,y,z,z</MEASUREMENT>
<MEASUREMENT>#,#,x,y,z,z</MEASUREMENT>
</PROFILE>
<PROFILE>
</PROFILE>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked!
I want to access the x and y data and edit the y data in each measurement per profile, is there some documentation about this? I'd like to learn how to do this.

Comment: Everything you get from this XML file is effectively a comma separated value - a `str` that you will have to parse. If you're new, you should probably read [An Informal Introduction to Python - Strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings), and the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str) on the `str` class. You'll want to use the `split(",")` method. Since you want to do calculations involving these values, you want to transform the `str` to an `int` or `float`. Let me know if you need more help/direction.